# What is a Hill Giant's reach for unarmed attacks and grapples?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, grapple, unarmed-combat, reach

The [Hill Giant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hill-giant) is Huge (occupies a 15'x15' space). It has a Greatclub weapon attack with reach 10'.

What is the Giant's unarmed reach? What is his reach for grappling?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The reach would be the default (5ft)

The reach keyword only applies to what the stat block attaches it to, in this case the greatclub.

There is no description of a Hill Giant's unarmed strike (you could certainly homebrew one) so it would follow the default rules:

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions

Grappling follows the same restrictions as it counts as a melee Attack action.

Comment: So it might be reasonable to allow a Hill Giant a 10' natural reach, but it isn't covered by RAW?

Comment: @NickBrown Seems so, although I would be curious if a Greatclub made for humans would have a 10' reach. Could extrapolate from there.

Comment: Controlled space, actual size, and reach are all different mechanics. Providing Reach to the Hill Giant as (as with everything) in your purview  as DM, but doing so *should* increase the CR and XP. See the BugBear for something whose reach is extended (lLong-Limbed trait)

Comment: @NickBrown Not covered by RAW - But it would be unlikely to make him significantly stronger in my opinion. After all, he normally wields a greatclub with reach anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Grapple is defined in the PHB as a "special melee attack"

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you can use the Attack action to make a Special melee attack, a grapple.

A greatclub has a standard 5' reach so we can assume that the bonus to the greatclub's reach comes from the Hill Giant's natural reach rather than just a really long greatclub. Therefore, I would assume that the Hill Giant has a 10 foot reach with all melee attacks, including grapple, due to it's natural large size.

But you can rule it however you want. Maybe it has a 5 foot reach and a 5 foot long great club. If you're the DM, it could go however you wish. Trust your instincts, but the former is how I would rule it.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment. A possible counter-argument to your answer might be that a _standard_ greatclub has 5' reach; this is a Hill Giant's greatclub, which might have a 10' reach due to its size. There's some text in the MM (don't have it to hand, can't provide a quote or page number) that talks about oversized creature weapons somewhere that might support such a counter-argument, but I don't have it to hand, so as it stands, mine is a somewhat weak counter-argument... Nonetheless, this is a well presented answer.

Comment: @NathanS - I would be very interested in that MM text if you can find it.  I cannot find anything like that anywhere.  Please look for it and provide it as a new answer if you find it.

Comment: @NickBrown I'm not sure exactly what quote I was thinking of, I can't find anything in the MM. The closest I can find was DMG pg 278, which talks about weapons damage of oversized weapons for larger creatures. This may _imply_ that an oversized weapon has a greater reach, but I've found nothing that explicitly says that, so I think this might be a bit weak for a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In *Storm King’s Thunder*, on page 50, under the "Defense of Goldenfields" subheading of the ["Attack on Goldenfields"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/skt/rumblings#AttackonGoldenfields) section, there is an unarmed Hill Giant’s statistics:

> If forced into melee combat, an unarmed hill giant can use its action to make two unarmed attacks. Replace the giant’s greatclub attack with the following attack option:
>
> > ***Unarmed Attack.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +8 to hit, **reach 10 ft.**, one target. *Hit:* 12 (3d4 + 5) bludgeoning damage.

Comment: This answer could be improved with the addition of some commentary explaining how the information that you've presented answers the question.